# How can solve this deprecationWarning?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I want multi requests using aiohttp.
I was wrapping aiohttp like this, and i was test like this

my code

```py
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession as AioClientSession


class ClientSession(AioClientSession):
    async def _get(self, session, url, params=None, **kwargs):
        async with session.get(url, params=params, **kwargs) as response:
            return await response.json()

    async def _post(self, session, url, data=None, **kwargs):
        async with session.post(url, data=data, **kwargs) as response:
            return await response.json()

    async def fetch_all(self, method, urls, loop, data=None, params=None, **kwargs):
        async with AioClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
            if method == "GET":
                results = await asyncio.gather(*[self._get(session, url, params=params, **kwargs) for url in urls])
            elif method == "POST":
                results = await asyncio.gather(*[self._post(session, url, data=data, **kwargs) for url in urls])
            else:
                assert False
            return results


def multi_requests_get(urls, params=None, **kwargs):
    session = ClientSession()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(session.fetch_all("GET", urls, loop, params=params, **kwargs))
    session.close()
    return result


def multi_requests_post(urls, data=None, **kwargs):
    session = ClientSession()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(session.fetch_all("POST", urls, loop, data=data, **kwargs))
    session.close()
    return result
```

test code

```py
urls = ["https://httpbin.org/get?{}={}".format(x, x) for x in range(10)]

result = multi_requests_get(urls=urls)

assert result
assert result[0]["args"] == {"0": "0"}
assert result[1]["args"] == {"1": "1"}
```

but this test return Warning like this:

```
The object should be created from async function
    loop=loop)
```

How can I avoid this warning?

Here is the full traceback

```
============================================================================= warnings summary ==============================================================================
base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_get
  /path/server/base/requests.py:122: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
    session = ClientSession()

base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_get
base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_post
  /env_path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:730: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
    loop=loop)

base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_get
base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_post
  /env_path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:735: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
    resolver = DefaultResolver(loop=self._loop)

base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_get
base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_post
  /env_path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/cookiejar.py:55: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
    super().__init__(loop=loop)

base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_get
  /path/darae/server/base/requests.py:125: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession.close' was never awaited
    session.close()

base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_post
  /path/server/base/requests.py:131: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
    session = ClientSession()

base/tests/test_aiohttp.py::AioHttpTest::test_post
  /path/server/base/requests.py:134: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession.close' was never awaited
    session.close()

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
=================================================================== 2 passed, 10 warnings in 1.93 seconds ===================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

`aiohttp.ClientSession` class MUST be instantiated inside coroutine function, not just a function.

All you need to do:

1. Remove parent class from your `ClientSession` - you already use it explicitly in your fetch_all and you don't need it there anymore.
2. Remove calls of `session.close()` - session DO close automatically by context manager in fetch_all.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the simple working example from [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html) and find a place where to place your `aiohttp.ClientSession() as client`:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(client):
  async with client.get('http://python.org') as resp:
    assert resp.status == 200
    return await resp.text()

async def main():
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
    html = await fetch(client)
    print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```